# Do the texts of Mahayana Buddhism or those of any other school posit that everything is to be regarded as ideation? (Idealism)

Tags: mahayana, academic-buddhism

Does Mahayana Buddhism or any other school of Buddhism posit the idea that the physical world does not exist apart from an observer's frame of reference, as in everything exists only in the mind as imagination?

Comment: hi Rodney. please define "idealism" in your question. thank you

Comment: Objective and subjective idealism. The idea that the physical world does not exist, but everything exists only in the mind as imagination

Comment: Please see: [What is the difference between Yogacara Buddhism and Idealism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10925/471), [Do Cittamatra / Yogacara explicitly refute the existence of an external world?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13790/471), [What are the arguments Yogacara makes to deny the reality of sensory objects?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/40977/471)

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Which is closer to what you are asking?
1. That which imagines is imagined.
2. That which imagines isn't imagined. There is a fundamental difference.

Comment: Is Mahayana Buddhism idealism, or does it say that the entire physical world exists independently of the minds of living beings?

Comment: I voted to close because it's not clear what OP is asking as he takes for granted that the meaning of the word 'mind' is commonly agreed upon whilst the meaning of this term is the base of essential controversies. It is therefore not clear what he is asking and i don't see how anyone can answer this rightfully.

Comment: I think op is essentially asking whether there is any school which posits that 'perceived objects' exist only in as far as perception exists or that the perceived objects can exist as not perceived objects. Which is kind of funny as the latter asks whether some schools hold that x can be both x and not x simultaneously and the former whether x is x only. Obviously anything perceived is dependent on perception and is therefore called 'the perceived' or an object of perception.

Answer (score 1):

> the idea that the physical world does not exist apart from an observer's frame of reference

This is agreeable for expression. As i understand it, the Theravadin texts posit this iow.

> as in everything exists only in the mind as imagination

This is dodgy. Which is closer to what you are asking?

1. That which imagines is imagined.
2. That which imagines isn't imagined.

There is a fundamental difference and #1 is closer to Theravada. #2 would be disagreeable.

Answer (score 0):

> Dependent on eye & forms, eye-consciousness arises...
>
> Dependent on ear & sounds, ear-consciousness arises...
>
> Dependent on nose & aromas, nose-consciousness arises...
>
> Dependent on tongue & flavors, tongue-consciousness arises...
>
> Dependent on body & tactile sensations, body-consciousness arises...
>
> Madhupindika Sutta

---

> Were someone to say, 'I will describe a coming, a going, a passing
> away, an arising, a growth, an increase, or a proliferation of
> consciousness apart from form, from feeling, from perception, from
> fabrications,' that would be impossible.
>
> Upaya Sutta

Comment: That is, Mahayana Buddhism says that the external physical world exists independently of our mind?

Comment: @Rodney - Not at all. Mahayana says that only the conceptions of what we perceive are actually the mind and because those conceptions are believed, it gives rise to solidity and fragmented ideas about a physical world.

Answer (score 0):

Ideation creates views. Ideation belongs to the domain of thought, which in Buddhism is defined to be one of the six senses, all prone to grasping and therefore suffering. The Buddha discusses the net of ideation/views in [DN1. The Prime Net](https://suttacentral.net/dn1/en/sujato), which emphasizes how ideation/views can trap us.

> When a mendicant truly understands the six fields of contacts’ origin, ending, gratification, drawback, and escape, they understand what lies beyond all these things.

Notice that, in the above, the Buddha points beyond all these things. The Buddha points beyond ideation. The Buddha points beyond views.

And this leads to a problem with a question that asks about "everything". It's a problem because "everything", which is literally "every" conceivable "thing", is a very slippery term, much like "infinity". Is everything countable? Some infinities are countable. Others are not.

The Buddha taught four Noble Truths. These truths all deal with suffering. In fact, the four Noble Truths deal with *all* suffering. They do not deal with "everything" unless we define "everything" as "all suffering". And in this one special case of "everything as all suffering", then yes, every *thing* is indeed suffering and there is also an end to suffering. Ideation belongs to the realm of forms. And the escape from forms is the formless, which lies beyond ideation.

> [DN34:1.4.27](https://suttacentral.net/dn34/en/sujato#dn34:1.4.27): Renunciation is the escape from sensual pleasures. The formless is the escape from form. Cessation is the escape from whatever is created, conditioned, and dependently originated.