# A summary explaining those ancient Indian philosophies of those non-Buddhist schools that had debated with Buddhist, especially Nalanda, masters?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy, doctrine

Can anyone share or tell: where can I find a summary explaining those ancient Indian philosophies of those non-Buddhist schools that had debated with Buddhist, especially Nalanda, masters? For example, those philosophies of those opponents in Indian Buddhism Śāstras (i.e. treaties).

I ask because I am studying some texts on and also pondering on the tenets system/theory of Indian Buddhism, and I would like to be rigorous in understanding what non-Buddhist philosophies are refuted grounding in reasoning by Indian Buddhism (Nalanda) masters.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a scholarly paper which lists the non-Buddhist schools and their philosophies (for which I don't have an answer).

The sutta which comes to mind as likely relevant to your question is [Brahmajāla Sutta (DN 1)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.01.0.bodh.html) -- which I think lists sixty or so wrong or non-Buddhist views.

Piya Tan as a more detailed (highly referenced) translation and commentary of this sutta (and of many other suttas too). The URLs on his site aren't quite stable but they're currently:

- [Brahma,jāla Sutta -- The Discourse on the Perfect Net -- D 1](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/25.2-Brahmajala-S-d1-Sutta-piya.pdf)
- [A Commentarial Guide to the Brahma,jāla Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/25.3-Brahmajala-S-Comy-piya.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any sources claiming actual debates taking place at Nalanda with non-Buddhists, but I do believe the [curriculum was such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nalanda) that debates took place with students trying to accurately and faithfully take the place of non-Buddhist Indian schools of thought, in order to show that Buddhist systems were superior and would overcome them.

> "Besides Theology and Philosophy, **frequent debates** and discussions necessitated competence in Logic. A student at the Mahavihara had to be well-versed in the systems of
> Logic associated with **all the different schools of thought of the time**
> as he was expected to defend Buddhist systems against the others."

I think this was achieved through internal debates where students of Nalanda would try to faithfully represent the other schools of thought.

Perhaps the [Sarvadarśanasaṅgraha](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/34125/34125-h/34125-h.htm) would also be of help for a non-Buddhist compendium of various extent philosophical schools of India in [the author's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidyaranya) extent period.

Answer (score 1):

[DN 2](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html) has descriptions of various shramanic teachings at the time of the Buddha including by the following teachers: Pūraṇa Kassapa, Makkhali Gosāla, Ajita Kesakambalī, Pakudha Kaccāyana, Sanjaya Belatthiputta and Mahavira (Jainism). Also [MN 101](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.101.than.html) further compares Jainism and Buddhism.

These suttas contrast the Buddha's teachings with these other teachings.

A good comparison between Hindu Vedanta and Buddhism can be found in [Vedanta and Buddhism: A Comparative Study](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/vonglasenapp/wheel002.html) by Helmuth von Glasenapp.

Please also see "[Have any Buddhist thinkers responded to the critique of the Brahma Sutras?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7426/471)".